# Copy files from one project to another after build

Tags: msbuild

I have a project for all my javascripts in side (that I made common for three projects).

During a build I want to move these scripts to the three projects, how can I do this by editing `.csproj` and how?

**Update:**

I have in the same solution `webapplication1` and `webapplication2` and i'm editing `.csproj` for webapplication1, and i want to copy all files in test folder

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(WDTargetDir)test\" 
          DestinationFolder="$(SolutionRoot)WebApplication2">
    </Copy>
  </Target>
```

However nothing is happening.

Answer (score 7):

There is two ways to do that:

_ Edit the .csproject, at the end of the file you should find a Target named AfterBuild (uncomment the target).

```
<ItemGroup>
    <JavascriptFiles Include="*.js"/>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Copy
        SourceFiles="@(JavascriptFiles)"
        DestinationFolder="PathWhereYouWantToCopyYourJavascriptFiles"
    />
</Target>
```

_ Post build events in visual studio (in project properties)

Comment: This is nice except that it will include the files in the project in VS and this is not something I want.

Comment: @MikaëlMayer To avoid that, put the `<ItemGroup>` _inside_ the `<Target>` element.

Comment: Will this run *every time* I build, or only when a *.js JavascriptFile is changed?

Comment: @Trinition: if you want control over whether unchanged files are going to be copied, use **SkipUnchangedFiles** boolean parameter (via [full documentation for the Copy task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx)).

Answer (score 2):

I found my solution:

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="test\CodeFile1.cs" 
          DestinationFolder="..\WebApplication2\scripts">
    </Copy>
  </Target>
```

Comment: Does this run *every time*, or just when CodeFile1.cs has changed?

Answer (score 2):

With VS2022 and MsBuild 17.6.3 the following works for my project:

```
    <Target Name="CopyFilesFromOneFolderToAnother" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
        <ItemGroup>
            <MySourceFolderContents Include="MySourceFolder\*"/>
        </ItemGroup>
        <Copy SourceFiles="%(MySourceFolderContents.Identity)"
              DestinationFolder="MyDestinationFolder"
              SkipUnchangedFiles="True"/>
    </Target>
```

The `<Target Name="AfterBuild">` does not fire, and the whole folder contents definition and call is slightly different.

Answer (score -1):

If you can use Visual Studio to build then use post [build events](http://visualstudiohacks.com/articles/general/customize-your-project-build-process/) in visual studio. Failing that if you have access to the command line just issue a [copy](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.computerhope.com%2Fcopyhlp.htm&ei=YaeBSYiAG8-X-gbAhYk2&usg=AFQjCNHX3seykl-9uufBf_oG1xM31IlfrQ&sig2=Rvx_NoaOOB0hPcVibtAQ5A) command