# c# how do i programmatically create a replica

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am developing winform app that runs in two differen pc's

I want to create a replica and get the changes over the internet

- How can i do that?
- & how can I create replica and sync it using C#?

any ideas will be appreciated

Comment: i think marwa thought about replication...

Comment: Yes I mean replication,Can u help?

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed. Jet Replication has a long and venerable history (though MS is phasing it out in favor of Sharepoint), and can work very well in certain scenarios. I wouldn't recommend it for an Internet situation, as it means using Indirect or Internet replication, which very quickly get complicated (and are subject to failure because of external dependencies). My Jet Replication Wiki has lots of resources: http://dfenton.com/DFA/Replication/

Comment: From the link to 'Jet Replication': _'[This is a despicable approach for Microsoft to use, and convinces me that Microsoft has active animus towards Jet Replication and doesn't want you to use it](http://dfenton.com/DFA/Replication/index.php?title=Things_not_to_believe_in_the_MS_documentation)'_. Anyways: [here it is](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/CH006252684.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are talking about replicating changes in one ms-access "database" such that two instances stay in sync, As such, you'd be better off abandoning ms-access and upscaling to a single centralised database.

Answer (score 1):

this sounds like a bad idea all around.

The common patterns apply;

1. use GUID id's,
2. send offline datasets,
3. cross fingers and look for a job that allows you to use other **free** tools, **suited** for the job http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx

Avoid conflict resolution (don't edit the same entities on both ends)

**Edit** 
PS. after visiting hamsaweb.net; if you need this to be web deployable on a shared host:

- [How to deploy SQL CE 4 CTP to shared hosting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468981/how-to-deploy-sql-ce-4-ctp-to-shared-hosting)

Comment: Jet Replication handled all these scenarios (full merge replication) before SQL Server did, for instance. It's still a usable platform, though not without its pitfalls.