# How to XCopy deploy SQL CE 4 in an EF 4.1 Code First Winforms app

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, sql-server-ce

Is is possible to xcopy deploy SQL CE 4 in an Entity Framework 4.1 code-first app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just worked out that I needed this section in my config:

```
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
   <add 
    name="SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0" 
    invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"
    description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0" 
    type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

I got that from here:

[How to deploy SQL CE 4 CTP to shared hosting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468981/how-to-deploy-sql-ce-4-ctp-to-shared-hosting/3859706#3859706)