# error while locating .sdf file on ASP.NET server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, sql-server-ce

I have done a web project ( using C# + SQL CE + ASP.NET )where it does few manupulation with .sdf file and results are displaye via ASP.net page . While i started working I hardcoded the path of the connection string and worked in my system . Now I want this database to be residing inside my server page.

> How do i get the working directory( localhost) so
>   that i can put that in connection
>   string ?

I tried using

> System.Environment.CommandLine but it throws me a error saying

```
"Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 98." The outcome of System.Environment.CommandLine is

Data Source= "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\9.0\WebDev.WebServer.EXE" /port:1438 /path:"C:\Documents and Settings\xxx\Desktop\Project\yyy\Deploy\EMSWEB\Back010\WEB\WEB" /vpath:"/WEB"/tEST.sdf;Persist Security Info=True;
```

Any idea ???

Comment: See my reply here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223359

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it work using

```
connectionString="data source=|DataDirectory|\test.sdf"
```

where as

```
 Data Source=" + (System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + "\\
```

Points to some directory like  this below.

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\9.0\WebDev.WebServer.EXE" /port:1438 /path:"C:\Documents and Settings\xxx\Desktop\Project\yyy\Deploy\EMSWEB\Back010\WEB\WEB" /vpath:"/WEB"/tEST.sdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005-ce

Comment: nope .. it doenst work out ...it points to some directory . I am tetsing it in desktop ,later stage willmove to server

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick advise: Never put this in to a real environment. SQL Server CE is NOT to be used as a database to a web application. It does not perform well with concurrent access.

And as @KBoek has said, connectionstrings.com should cover any of your connection string problems. Whether it is Desktop or Server, it is only a matter of specifying the path correctly to the database. I suggest you keep the .sdf file in the same directory as your other files

and use something like

```
Data Source=" + (System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + "\\MyData.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;
```