# Is EF Code First w/SQLCE 4 bin deployable?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, shared-hosting, bin, code-first

I am planning to create a MVC page that will use EF CodeFirst and SQLCE 4.0. Are this technologies bin deployable/ shared hosted friendly?

I am currently using GoDaddy with .Net4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
I have a couple of sites doing just this.

Comment: It took me a long while, but after a lot of trail and error and following [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762857/using-sql-server-ce-4-on-a-remote-host-with-mvc-3)  I got it to half work... but now I am getting this error
            `Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy. &nbsp;To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.` I thought it should work without full trust :/