# Getting Security Exception SQLCE 4, Code First CTP 5 & Shared Hosting

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, shared-hosting, code-first, securityexception

I've been trying to setup a webpage with MVC3 Razor, SQLCE 4 and Code First, the last two downloaded from Nuget, so it is EF Code First CTP5.

I've had a lot of trouble, but I manage to move forward by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762857/using-sql-server-ce-4-on-a-remote-host-with-mvc-3/4903788#4903788)

However now I am getting this Security Exception

**Description**: `The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy. To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.`

I thought it should work without full trust so I don't know what is wrong now.

I am using GoDaddy shared hosting with .Net 4 and IIS7

What could be the issue?

EDIT:

I haven't modified the web.config, except for setting custom errors = false to be able to see the exceptions, otherwise I have the webconfig that was generated by using Nuget to get and configure SQLCE and Code first

This is how it is:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors
   mode="Off"
   />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Well it seems that its [EF CTP 5](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/adonetefx/thread/3c893ee3-9dec-431a-82ab-13c2eece6996) fault :(

Comment: Weird, I don't have that problem. I think that is a trust issue but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Jesus, what version of CodeFirst are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm as I said in the first comment on the question, it is an error with Code First CTP5, which uses full trust instead of medium trust. [Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/adonetefx/thread/3c893ee3-9dec-431a-82ab-13c2eece6996)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug with CTP5 that will be fixed in final release.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/641462/ef-code-first-issue-with-medium-trust