# How to deploy SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0?

Tags: sql-server-2008, deployment, sql-server-ce, ado, xcopy

How do i deploy [Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876)?

---

SQL Server Compact Edition (currently at version 4.0) is:

> a free, embedded database that software developers can use for building Windows desktop applications. It has a small footprint and supports private deployment of its binaries within the application folder.

But how do you actually deploy it?

- Microsoft says it **can** be [deployed within the application folder (*good*) and supports xcopy deployment](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/blog/SQL-Server-Compact-Edition-40-Toolkit-v2-Dont-leave-your-Visual-Studio-without-it).
- Microsoft also says it **cannot** be [deployed within the application folder (*bad*), and does not support xcopy deployment](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920700).
- some people have [examples of it using simple xcopy deployment](http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/how-to-deploy-the-sqlserver-compact-edition-software-locally/), but they don't go into the details required to complete the deployment

The problem is that you cannot use the ADO OLEdb provider unless it is registered. Registering an OLEdb provider has to be done as an administrator. That means that SQL Server Compact edition will fail with users who are not an administrator.

SQL Server Compact 4.0 comes with a `redist_enu.txt` file:

> The listed .exe files each install its enclosed components to a specific location on the destination computer.  This helps to ensure serviceability and technical support.  The .dll files enclosed in these .exe files are also available separately in this redist.txt.  However, distributions of these separate .dlls may result in issues of serviceability.  For more details, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=94589
>
> Private deployment detection via BreadCrumb:  Private deployment of just the native stack and explicit loading of SQL Server Compact Assembly via Assembly.LoadFrom(), .local file, or the use of DLL/COM redirection strategies are not supported and may result in serviceability issues.  For more information see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/835322 and http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375142.aspx
>
> ### Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0
>
> SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.exe
>   SSCERuntime_x86-DEU.exe
>   SSCERuntime_x86-FRA.exe
>   SSCERuntime_x86-JPN.exe
>   SSCERuntime_x86-RUS.exe
>   SSCERuntime_x86-ESN.exe
>   SSCERuntime_x86-ITA.exe
>   SSCERuntime_x86-KOR.exe
>   SSCERuntime_x86-CHT.exe
>   SSCERuntime_x86-CHS.exe
>   SSCERuntime_x64-ENU.exe
>   SSCERuntime_x64-DEU.exe
>   SSCERuntime_x64-FRA.exe
>   SSCERuntime_x64-JPN.exe
>   SSCERuntime_x64-RUS.exe
>   SSCERuntime_x64-ESN.exe
>   SSCERuntime_x64-ITA.exe
>   SSCERuntime_x64-KOR.exe
>   SSCERuntime_x64-CHT.exe
>   SSCERuntime_x64-CHS.exe
>   sqlcese40.dll
>   sqlceqp40.dll
>   sqlceoledb40.dll
>   sqlceca40.dll
>   sqlceme40.dll
>   sqlcecompact40.dll
>   sqlceer40en.dll
>   sqlceer40cn.dll/sqlceer40zh-CHS.dll
>   sqlceer40de.dll
>   sqlceer40es.dll
>   sqlceer40fr.dll
>   sqlceer40it.dll
>   sqlceer40ja.dll
>   sqlceer40ko.dll
>   sqlceer40tw.dll/sqlceer40zh-CHT.dll
>   sqlceer40ru.dll
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity.dll

but it doesn't give any information about how to redistribute SQL Server Compact 4.0.

Randomly spellunking around the undocumented `Program Files` folder i found 7 dlls:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v4.0\
      sqlceoledb40.dll
      sqlceqp40.dll
      sqlcese40.dll
      sqlceca40.dll
      sqlcecompact40.dll
      sqlceer40EN.dll
      sqlceme40.dll
```

**Note:** There are also some child folders with more dlls

i tried copying these 7 dll's to a folder, and tried to open an [ADO Connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) using [the connection string](http://www.quickersite.com/r/default.asp?iID=HFJJLH&iPostID=MFLDKE):

```
Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="store.sdf"
```

but it fails with `0x80004005 Unspecified error`

[i tried frobbing the widget, but it grobbed the frobber.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/01/20/10117963.aspx)

Comment: I've never done this myself, but is the documentation unclear? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: See my blog post here: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-sql-server-compact-40-with.html Using SQL Server Compact 4.0 with Desktop Private Deployment and a Setup project (MSI) (part 2)

Comment: You reference `app.config`, which i assume means a .NET application. i happen to be using a native application with xcopy deployment.

Comment: @Pondlife The page *How to: Deploy a SQL Server Compact 4.0 Database with an Application* is perfectly clear. Unfortunately it also doesn't work. They assume a .NET application, and ignore the required registration of OLEDB COM dll `sqlceoledb40.dll`.

Comment: Document this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ado/commit) by backing it do it now before documentation is [gone forever](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356294/removing-documentation-reputation-archive-and-links?cb=1)!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

i've created the solution.

SQL Server Compact Edition is comprised of 7 dlls:

- `sqlceme40.dll` The undocumented, native, flat API library (The .net `System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll` assembly is a wrapper around this dll)
- `sqlceca40.dll` A COM dll that implements `Engine`, `Replication`, `Error` and a few other COM objects
- `sqlceoledb40.dll` A COM dll that implements an OLEdb provider for SSCE (allowing the use of ADO)
- `sqlcese40.dll` *unknown*
- `sqlceqp40.dll` *unknown*
- `sqlcecompact40.dll` *unknown*
- `sqlceer40en.dll` *unknown*

The problem with trying to simply ship these dlls is that two of them are **COM** objects. COM object dll's need to be *registered*, e.g.:

```
>regsvr32 sqlceca40.dll
>regsvr32 sqlceoledb40.dll
```

The problem is that registering a COM object requires *administrative* privileges ([using a global solution to solve a local problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/12/11/9193695.aspx)). This means that your users would

- have to *install* your application (which you don't want to do)
- requires your users to have administrative permissions (which you don't want to do)

Fortunately, starting in 2001 with Windows XP, Microsoft solved this COMmon problem: [Registration-Free COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx).

First, you will declare that your application has a ***"dependancy"*** on SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0. You do this by authoring an assembly manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"> 
    <assemblyIdentity 
        version="1.0.0.0"
        processorArchitecture="X86"
        name="client"
        type="win32"
    /> 

    <description>Hyperion Pro</description> 

    <!-- We have a dependancy on SQL Server CE 4.0 -->
    <dependency>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity
                type="win32"
                name="Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.4.0"
                version="4.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="x86"
            />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </dependency>
```

```xml
    <!-- We are high-dpi aware on Windows Vista -->
    <asmv3:application xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <asmv3:windowsSettings
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
            <dpiAware>true</dpiAware>
        </asmv3:windowsSettings>
    </asmv3:application>

    <!-- We were designed and tested on Windows 7 -->
    <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
        <application>
            <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows 7 -->
            <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
            <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows Vista -->
            <!--supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/-->
        </application>
    </compatibility>

    <!-- Disable file and registry virtualization -->
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges>
                <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/>
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

You can place this file *beside* your executable (as `Hyperion.exe.manifest`), or you can build it into your application as an `RT_MANIFEST` resource.

Notice that we have a dependancy against as assembly called `Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.4.0`. We create this assembly first by creating a **directory** called:

> Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.4.0

When you deploy your application, you will place all 7 dll's that comprise this *"assembly"* into this `Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.4.0` subfolder, along with a special `.manifest` file:

```xml
C:\
╰──Users
   ╰──Ian
      ╰──AppData
         ╰──Local
            ╰──Hyperion Pro
               ├──Hyperion.exe
               ├──Hyperion.exe.manifest
               ╰──Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.4.0
                  ├──sqlceme40.dll
                  ├──sqlceca40.dll
                  ├──sqlceoledb40.dll
                  ├──sqlcese40.dll
                  ├──sqlceqp40.dll
                  ├──sqlcecompact40.dll
                  ├──sqlceer40en.dll
                  ╰──Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.4.0.manifest
```

In other words, the application folder contains your application, and the **Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.4.0** folder:

```xml
 Directory of C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Local\Hyperion Pro

05/29/2012  09:23 AM         1,899,008 Hyperion.exe
05/28/2012  01:46 PM             1,587 Hyperion.exe.manifest
05/29/2012  09:27 AM    <DIR>          Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.4.0
           2 File(s)      1,900,675 bytes
           1 Dir(s)  20,851,503,104 bytes free
```

The next part of your task is to define the `Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.4.0.manifest` file. Registration-free COM allows a manifest file to declare all the COM objects and their clsid's. This took a lot of reverse engineering. But the assembly manifest for SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0 is:

**Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.4.0.manifest**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">

<assemblyIdentity 
       type="win32"
       name="Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.4.0"
       processorArchitecture="x86"
       version="4.0.0.0" />

<!-- OLEDB Provider -->
<file name = "sqlceoledb40.dll">
    <comClass
            description = "Microsoft SQL Server Compact OLE DB Provider for Windows"
            clsid="{2006C53A-C915-41EA-BAA9-9EAB3A1FBF97}"
            threadingModel = "Both"
            progid = "Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.4.0" />
</file>

<!-- Native flat engine library -->
<file name="sqlceme40.dll" />

<!-- Engine and Replication COM object -->
<file name="sqlceca40.dll">
    <comClass description="Active SSCE Engine Object"
            clsid="{68D45319-3702-4837-9F8E-DA6845D82482}"
            threadingModel="Both"
            progid="SSCE.Engine.4.0" />
    <comClass description="SSCE Error Object"
            clsid="{36228F21-B5C7-4054-8DC2-47D3E236E8B5}"
            threadingModel="Both"
            progid="SSCE.Error.4.0" />
    <comClass description="SSCE Param Object"
            clsid="{0B3A7B75-A9B0-4580-9AA5-1A7DA47AD1CB}"
            threadingModel="Both"
            progid="SSCE.Param.4.0" />
    <comClass description="Active SSCE Replication Object"
            clsid="{11D5B2D4-26A4-44F5-A48B-0FAC3A919ED8}"
            threadingModel="Both"
            progid="SSCE.Replication.4.0" />
    <comClass description="Active SSCE remote data access Object"
            clsid="{58BC9AD6-BF11-40B3-9AB1-E3F2ED784C08}"
            threadingModel="Both"
            progid="SSCE.RemoteDataAccess.4.0" />

    <typelib tlbid="{CE4AACFA-3CFD-4028-B2D9-F272314F07C8}"
            version="4.0" 
            helpdir=""/>
</file>

<comInterfaceExternalProxyStub 
    name="ISSCEEngine"
    iid="{10EC3E45-0870-4D7B-9A2D-F4F81B6B7FA2}"
    proxyStubClsid32="{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
    baseInterface="{00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
    tlbid = "{CE4AACFA-3CFD-4028-B2D9-F272314F07C8}" />

<comInterfaceExternalProxyStub 
    name="ISSCEError"
    iid="{31155A3B-871D-407F-9F73-DEBFAC7EFBE3}"
    proxyStubClsid32="{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
    baseInterface="{00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
    tlbid = "{CE4AACFA-3CFD-4028-B2D9-F272314F07C8}" />

<comInterfaceExternalProxyStub 
    name="ISSCERDA"
    iid="{4F04F79D-1FF1-4DCD-802B-3D51B9356C14}"
    proxyStubClsid32="{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
    baseInterface="{00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
    tlbid = "{CE4AACFA-3CFD-4028-B2D9-F272314F07C8}" />

<comInterfaceExternalProxyStub 
    name="ISSCEParams"
    iid="{A78AFF90-049C-41EC-B1D8-665968AAC4A6}"
    proxyStubClsid32="{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
    baseInterface="{00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
    tlbid = "{CE4AACFA-3CFD-4028-B2D9-F272314F07C8}" />

<comInterfaceExternalProxyStub 
    name="ISSCEParam"
    iid="{A9876C60-2667-44E5-89DB-E9A46ED392C0}"
    proxyStubClsid32="{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
    baseInterface="{00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
    tlbid = "{CE4AACFA-3CFD-4028-B2D9-F272314F07C8}" />

<comInterfaceExternalProxyStub 
    name="ISSCEErrors"
    iid="{C40143CA-E9F9-4FF4-B8B4-CC02C064FC1B}"
    proxyStubClsid32="{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
    baseInterface="{00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
    tlbid = "{CE4AACFA-3CFD-4028-B2D9-F272314F07C8}" />

<comInterfaceExternalProxyStub 
    name="ISSCEMerge"
    iid="{C6EB397F-D585-428D-A4F4-454A1842CB47}"
    proxyStubClsid32="{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
    baseInterface="{00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
    tlbid = "{CE4AACFA-3CFD-4028-B2D9-F272314F07C8}" />

<file name="sqlceqp40.dll" />
<file name="sqlcese40.dll" />
<file name="sqlcecompact40.dll" />
<file name="sqlceer40EN.dll" />

</assembly>
```

The a final gotcha is that, in the same way we have a dependancy on an assembly called `Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.4.0`, SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0 in turn has a dependancy on an assembly called `Microsoft.VC90.CRT`. Fortunately your install of SQLCE ships with a copy of this assembly:

```xml
Microsoft.VC90.CRT
├──Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest 
╰──msvcr90.dll
```

This means the final directory structure is:

```xml
C:\
╰──Users
   ╰──Ian
      ╰──AppData
         ╰──Local
            ╰──Hyperion Pro
               ├──Hyperion.exe
               ├──Hyperion.exe.manifest
               ╰──Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.4.0
                  ├──Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.4.0.manifest
                  ├──sqlceme40.dll
                  ├──sqlceca40.dll
                  ├──sqlceoledb40.dll
                  ├──sqlcese40.dll
                  ├──sqlceqp40.dll
                  ├──sqlcecompact40.dll
                  ├──sqlceer40en.dll
                  ╰──Microsoft.VC90.CRT
                     ├──Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest
                     ╰──msvcr90.dll
```

Comment: My, what a trip 'round Robin Hood's Barn. There's a lot simpler way: [private deployment](http://erikej.blogspot.sk/2013/11/entity-framework-6-sql-server-compact-4_25.html). You can take it a step further by not even copying the Private assemblies and VC++ files into your project--just link to them instead and set the Build Action to Copy if Newer.

Comment: @InteXX All that requires, and assumes, Visual Studio. There are other IDEs that build native Win32/64 executables.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. That particular Private Deployment procedure only works with Visual Studio. Others will need another way. This is a nice writeup on Registration-Free COM. I'll refer to it when I have to do that next. Good job.

Comment: I'm not sure about your use of "Hyperion" here. Is this the name of your app or is it a literal that must be included?

Comment: @InteXX Hyperion is the made-up name of an application.

Comment: It is not working under Windows 10 64 bits unless I move the following files in the same directory as the executable: sqlcese40.dll, sqlceme40.dll, sqlceqp40.dll.

Answer (score 8):

For Sql Server Ce 4.0 SP1:

Instead of tackling all the gritty stuff of deployment, I just opted to include the setup files themselves into my exe as EmbeddedResource and did this little helper:

```cs
 public static class RedistHelper
    {
        private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(
                                              MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        private static readonly string SqlCeRedistName64 = "SSCERuntime_x64-ENU.exe";
        private static readonly string SqlCeRedistName32 = "SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.exe";
        private static readonly Dictionary<string, Assembly> Assemblies = 
                        new Dictionary<string, Assembly>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

        private static string SqlCeRedistName
        {
            get 
            {
                return Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem 
                                       ? SqlCeRedistName64 
                                       : SqlCeRedistName32;
            }
        }

        public static bool IsSqlCeInstalled()
        {
            RegistryKey localKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine,
                                                           RegistryView.Registry64);
            RegistryKey ret = localKey.OpenSubKey(
                    @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v4.0\ENU");
            return ret != null;
        }

        private static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int read;
                while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }

        public static Assembly OnCurrentDomainOnAssemblyResolve(object sender,
                                                                ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            Assembly dll;
            var name = new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll";
            if (!Assemblies.TryGetValue(name, out dll))
            {
                Assembly res = typeof(RedistHelper).Assembly;
                using (Stream input =
                           res.GetManifestResourceStream(typeof(RedistHelper), name))
                {
                    if (input == null)
                    {
                        Log.WarnFormat("Assembly {0} does not contain {1}", res, name);
                        return null;
                    }
                    dll = Assembly.Load(ReadFully(input));
                    if (dll == null)
                    {
                        Log.WarnFormat("Assembly {0} failed to load.", name);
                        return null;
                    }
                    Log.InfoFormat("Loaded assembly {0}.", name);
                    Assemblies[name] = dll;
                    return dll;
                }
            }
            return dll;
        }

        public static void InstallSqlCe()
        {
            using (Stream stream =
                       typeof(RedistHelper).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(
                           typeof(RedistHelper), SqlCeRedistName))
            {
                Debug.Assert(stream != null);
                byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)stream.Length];
                stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), SqlCeRedistName);

                if (File.Exists(path))
                    File.Delete(path);

                File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);

                Process process = new Process
                                  {
                                      StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                                                  {
                                                      FileName = path,
                                                      UseShellExecute = true
                                                  }
                                  };
                process.Start();
                process.WaitForExit();
            }
        }
    }
```

The only thing that really gave me a headache was referencing the System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll - it simply wouldnt IlMerge, so instead I loaded it on demand, in my main:

```cs
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += RedistHelper.OnCurrentDomainOnAssemblyResolve;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if something changed or not. But with the latest SQL Server CE nuget package, the application manifests are no longer needed. You will get two sets of binaries: x86, and amd64. Just copy them to your target folder under x86 and/or amd64 sub directory.

```
|--Your App Dir
   |--x86 (x86 sql ce binaries)
   |--amd64 (amd64 sql ce binaries)
```

And you're good to go. Looks like the System.Data.SqlCe.dll can automatically find and load the native binaries. You can also deploy them in the app dir if your app is only targeted for one platform.