# Connecting to database(MS Access) in asp.net c#(hosting website)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I have a hosted website, and I need to add a database with password and log-in information. (MS Access DB), I tried a lot but can't connect with it (on local machine it works). I tried to change connection string but it still doesn't work. Database is in folder App_Data. Here's what I type in `Login.aspx` page:

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
   + Server.MapPath("~\\App_Data\\WebSiteDatabase.accdb");
con.Open();
```

This does not work. What do I need to change? I've put my web site on somee.com

Comment: Why are you not using the included SQL Express database?

Comment: It's a task for education....

Comment: Is the "program" Access installed on the server?  Also, I cringe whenever I see someone using Access with a website.  Please don't do it.

Comment: http://somee.com/DOKA/DoHelpTopics.aspx?docode=false&thnid=91 they have this but I don't understand where I should write it

Comment: Dump access - its not for hosted web environments. Use SQL CE 4 instead - because thats what its for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739845/how-to-deploy-sql-server-compact-edition-4-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check the help page on SOMEE for connecting to an access database?

QUOTE FROM Somee.com help:

> Connect to MS access database usin DSN-less connection
>   Doka only
>   provides DSN-less connection to the Access databases, because they are
>   much faster and there is no possible names conflict.     Most of the
>   problems are in choosing right connection string. Here is an example
>   of tested connection string to MS Access database:
>           We suppose that your **database** resides in **“Database” subfolder** and it name is **“TestDB.mdb”**.
>   You’ll have to use 
>   `Server.MapPath(“Database\TestDB.mdb”)` in order to get physical
>   location of database.

So connection string would be:

```
"PROVIDER=MICROSOFT.JET.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE=" & Server.MapPath("Database\TestDB.mdb")
```

And the way to utilize it:

```
OleDbConnection conn = null;
OleDbDataReader reader = null;
try
{
    conn = new OleDbConnection(
        "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " + 
        "Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("Database/TestDB.mdb"));
    conn.Open();

    OleDbCommand cmd = 
        new OleDbCommand("Select * FROM Table1", conn);
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    datagrid.DataSource = reader;
    datagrid.DataBind();
}
    //        catch (Exception e)
    //        {
    //            Response.Write(e.Message);
    //            Response.End();
    //        }
finally
{
    if (reader != null)  reader.Close();
    if (conn != null)  conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: I saw this. but everything VS sayes that & can't be used in string and all is read

Comment: What does that mean? What cant be used in a string? All what is read?

Comment: I tried to change con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
   + Server.MapPath("~\\App_Data\\WebSiteDatabase.accdb");
to "PROVIDER=MICROSOFT.JET.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE=" & Server.MapPath("App_Data\WebSiteDatabase.accdb")
and it shows errors

Comment: So you can connect to the database, you don't have write access?

Comment: what errors? can you be more specific?

Comment: This is the website http://testeducationmagazine.somee.com/ when I try to login it shows error

Comment: "PROVIDER=MICROSOFT.JET.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE=" & Server.MapPath("App_Data\WebSiteDatabase.accdb")
i have to write in html code ?

Comment: Try following a tutorial. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971485.aspx and remove the password until you have it working and then add the password once you are sure you can connect.

Comment: I read this. Changed the connection string . on local machine it runs good , but still when I put the site on hosting it shows error

Comment: **Welcome to the 2k club. Congratulations.**