# C# Small database project with sql server ce

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-ce

I am developing a simple database desktop application using windows forms and c#. I have decided to use Sql Server CE for my app. I am using following things:
1) Sql server ce 4.0
2) .net framwork 4.0
3) ms visual studio 2010

Now sorry but I have a thousand questions to ask
1) Is my choice of sql server ce correct or what are the alternatives

2) Basically i have developed apps on android and there i dont need to check if the database is already created or not but here in forms apps, do i need to:
a) check if the database is already created
b) then check if all tables have been created
c) can i do the above two steps( a and b ) just by checking if my sdf already exists and be rest assured

3) Do I need to have .net installed on my client's pcs or my app is a stand alone one( because i used sql server ce - no sql server installation)

Buddies these all questions have made me puzzled.
Please help and share your experiences.

Cheers and thanks in advance!!!

Comment: did you find an answer to your question?

Comment: Ya I did but didnt accepted any answers because I think all three are right up there. What to do in such case???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Depends on the nature of your program. Understand that SQL CE is most suitable for deployed client applications as SQL CE can be *privately deployed*.
2. When your program first loads,  you should check if the database file already exists. If the database does not exist you should create the database *and* create the appropriate tables like [*this*](https://gist.github.com/ByteBlast/7171967).
3. The client machine must have the net framework installed! In *addition*, you will either have to require that the end-user has a [*public installation*](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/compact.aspx) available or [*privately deploy*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739845/how-to-deploy-sql-server-compact-edition-4-0) the appropriate class libraries with your applications.

Answer (score 1):

1) It is correct

2) c) should be enough - just create your db when there is no sdf - as long as the tables are always the same it is ok.

3) Yes because you're developing a .NET application. Use of SQL CE does not change anything. Your client machines will need .NET 4.0 installed. SQL CE itself doe not have to be installed - you need to include all the SQL CE files within your app. All files needed are in the 'private' folder in the SQL CE package.

Answer (score 1):

1) Is my choice of sql server ce correct or what are the alternatives

> I would say it depends on your need or requirement. But SQL Server CE
>   has limitations specially you can store upto 4GB data. So before
>   choosing the database think of your need.

2) forms apps, do i need to: a) check if the database is already created b) then check if all tables have been created.

> Not necessary, But during the database operations if those are not available you can display message.

3) Do I need to have .net installed on my client's pcs or my app is a stand alone one( because i used sql server ce - no sql server installation)

> Yes, Client machine should have .net frame work installed. But .net
>   frame is packed with windows OS. But you have to make sure right
>   version is available. If you are building MSI package it will do it
>   for you, It can check .net frame work version exist in the client
>   machine.