# Can .mdf use as embedded database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-express

I am new to C# and SQL Server databases, so this may be a stupid question but I am confused.

I want to setup an embedded database on a client machine automatically when he installs my application. I know SQL Server Compact Edition is there but there are so many restrictions in SQL Server CE.

Can I use `.mdf` files as an embedded database? If yes then how can I setup it on client machine automatically? or is there any other option to solve my problem?

Comment: Yes, this could be done. If you don't need more than a single database you might also consider looking into SQLLite

Comment: Contradicting @drew_w here: but **NO** this cannot be done - in order to use an `.mdf`, you always **must install** some form of a SQL Server **server-side** component. An `.mdf` file cannot be used by any "embedded" database that you can ship as a set of DLL's with your application - `.mdf` need a SQL **Server** to run

Comment: There is apparently a way, but it's not simple: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10800781/542417

Comment: @marc_s Technically true, but I think there's a fair chance that SQL Server LocalDB is sufficient for the purposes of the OP, even though there are good reasons for not actually calling it "embedded".

Comment: @hvd: okay - but even "LocalDB" **requires** an installation! You cannot just ship a few DLLs with your app (which is what I'd consider an "embedded" database) - it's really still a **server** running on that PC where the app runs

Comment: @marc_s Fully agreed, I just think the OP may not be aware of such an option, so the word "embedded" in the question may not be intended to exclude such an answer.

Comment: @marc_s The point of the question is to ask if there is an easy way to deploy an MDB to a client as part of an application. I don't think the OP cares about the semantics of the word "embedded". To that end, what they are asking for is possible. SQLLite is a much better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommended to use SQLite. It is simpler to deploy. Also, SQL Server Compact appears to be discontinued.

[Is SQL Server Compact discontinued from Visual Studio 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363374/is-sql-server-compact-discontinued-from-visual-studio-2013)

You can use SQLite which **doesn't** require any installation on the client machine.

SQLite depends on the Visual C++ runtime, but you don't need to install it on the client machine. The [system.data.sqlite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) download page contains several "static" packages that already contain the runtime.

> All the "static" packages contain either native or mixed-mode assembly
>   binaries linked statically to the appropriate version of the Visual
>   C++ runtime. Typically, these packages are used in cases where
>   customer machines may not have the necessary version of the Visual C++
>   runtime installed and it cannot be installed due to limited
>   privileges.

For example, on my machine I am running Windows 8.1 x64 so I went under Precompiled Statically-Linked Binaries for 64-bit Windows (.NET Framework 4.0) and downloaded sqlite-netFx40-static-binary-x64-2010-1.0.90.0.zip.

> This binary package contains all the binaries for the x64 version of
>   the System.Data.SQLite 1.0.90.0 (3.8.2) package. The Visual C++ 2010
>   SP1 runtime for x64 is statically linked. The .NET Framework 4.0 is
>   required.

I then unzipped the package and ran test.exe to make sure everything works. Zero installation required.

Comment: thanks dude. it's really helpful. but my client keep preferring sql-server database. :( is there any way to use .mdf or sql-server express as embedded database? if not then last option is SQLite for me.