# Maven or Gradle Spring app with in-memory MSSQL DB from MDF file for tests

Tags: sql-server, spring, maven, spring-boot, gradle

Is there a plugin, library or anything else that could allow me to bring an MDF file as in-memory database for testing in my Spring app with maven or gradle?

Comment: No, no plugin/libraray/thing google&me aware of. But if you are able to ["mdf2sql"](https://www.google.com/search?q=mdf+to+sql) it, your options (with spring, maven/gradle + SQL) will multiply! ..see also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21685840/592355

Comment: The thing is that I am working with a super-duper legacy database and trying to migrate it or simulate it will end up in a very error-prone process of development and testing.