# How to run desktop application with database locally without installing any database Server?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, database, desktop-application

I wanted to create a desktop application with database, am using Visual Studio 2013 and C# , Can anybody suggest me what server I used to create my database, in order to run my application in my client's system locally with out installing any database server in client's system [ie, with out installing MsSql server or MySql server or Acess], I want my app works properly when installing my own application's exe file ?

And Now am using MSSQL server with my application , Is there any way run this application in client's system locally with out installing MSSQL Server?  [my application front end works when I install .Net FrameWork 4.5 , I need something like this for my .mdf databse in Sql Server]

somebody says about SQL Server Compact ,but i don't know how to use it

Comment: instead of your local db name you have to give IP `Data Source=xx.xxx.80.40`

Comment: `desktop application with database` ???? so you need a database, where does it reside if you will not install it locally?

Comment: i think its not a good practice to install the whole sql server to client system when installing own developed application , but I want a running environment for .mdf database (just like installing frameworks for proper working of front-end )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SQL Server Compact, which can either be installed separately or deployed as part of your application.

See here: [How to deploy SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739845/how-to-deploy-sql-server-compact-edition-4-0)

And here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa983326(v=vs.110).aspx

Your DB code in your app - apart from your connection string - should not need to change as you're already using some version of SQL Server.

There is also SQLite, which is as far as I know is well regarded, but I know very little about it. http://www.sqlite.org/

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

It is not unusual for an application to require an existing functional database server. Of course this is appropriate only if your target audience is technical enough to install the prerequisite on their own, or if the target environment is guaranteed to already meet your prerequisite.

If not, you need to fall back to an [embedded database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3639846/1446005).

Comment: In a Windows/C# environment, [SQL CE probably is the prefered option](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31918057/1446005).