# Install SQL Server compact database .Exe file automatcally when I install WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-ce, setup-project, setup-deployment

I had developed a WPF application, and its backend is a SQL Server CE `.SDF` file. In setup and deployment project I added `.SDF` file in it

The issue is: to access and get records from the `.SDF` file we require an additional software. Please find the below Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=17876

It has 2 exe files

1. 64 Bit
2. 86/32 Bit

Visual Studio directly installs this software when we install VS

On a client system, I didn't find these files so I am unable to access the `.SDF` file and get records from it

I need to Copy these files in Application folder and Automatically Install it if the above software is not Present in the PC

Now I am Manually Installing these software(exe ) in Each PC

Comment: Very unclear - what **exactly** do you mean by *SQL Server Compact DB exe file* ?? SQL Server Compact is just a handful of DLL's that you package with your application, and a  `.sdf` file that you package or create - there's no external `.exe` of any sort needed to work with a SQL Server CE database file .....

Comment: Marcs Please check my Question I had Updated the Question

Comment: Again: ***NO*** you don't need any additional EXE based software! You need to simply **ship** the relevant SQL Server Compact DLL's along with your software, **and that's it!** No additional software, no additional install needed!

Answer (score 3):

You're mistaken - to deploy a SQL Server CE 4.0 based application, you **do NOT** need to deploy and/or install any additional software to your client system - it suffices to include the necessary, relevant SQL Server CE 4.0 DLL's into your application (into the `bin` or `lib` folder or something), and just ship those files with your application. That's **all** you need - no server-side or client-side install needed ! (That's the **WHOLE POINT** of using SQL Server CE, after all!)

See these links for in-depth descriptions of how to do it:

Right here on Stackoverflow:

- [How to deploy SQL Server Compact 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739845/how-to-deploy-sql-server-compact-edition-4-0)

Another way to do it:

- [How to deploy the SQL Server Compact Edition software locally](https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/how-to-deploy-the-sqlserver-compact-edition-software-locally/)

Official MSDN documentation:

- [How to deploy a SQL Server Compact 4.0 database with an application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326.aspx)