# SQL Server compact 4 silent install

Tags: sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4, silent-installer

My program uses SQL Ce 4 and I want to install my program and install the SQL CE4 at the same time, but silently.

Searching the internet, someone says that I need to copy/paste the .dll to the instalation folder. But it's not working, I don't know what I did wrong...

The dll are located in this folder: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v4.0\Private`

[image: Folder]

I already tried to put that 2 dll (in the picture) and "x86" folder inside the folder of my program. Didn't worked.

Any ideas, what dll is needed?

Comment: Have a look at this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10431701/29467

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223359/cant-get-sql-server-compact-3-5-4-to-work-with-asp-net-mvc-2/3223450#3223450